# Compare user input with values stored in vector

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, user-input, findandmodify

This is my program thus far. It compiles but gets stuck and crashes on the last part. I want to repeat user's string input and replace any bad words found in the string with "****". Most likely my error is in find_Poop_inSentence. "Debug Assertion failed. vector subscript out of range"

```
void find_Poop_inSentence(vector<string> & v1, vector<string> & v2, string sub);

int main()
{
cout << "Howdy partner, tell me some words you don't take kindly to.\n";
vector<string>bad_words;
string word;

while (cin >> word)
{
    cin.ignore();
    bad_words.push_back(word);
    if (word == "exit")
        break;

}
cout << "Ok partner, got it!\n";
cout << "Now say something and I'll repeat it back to you. Don't worry, I'll bleep out the words that you don't like.\n";

word = "";
vector<string> random_sentence; 
while (cin >> word)
{
    cin.ignore();
    random_sentence.push_back(word);
    if (cin.get() == '\n')
        break;

}

find_Poop_inSentence(bad_words, random_sentence, "****");

cout << "You said: ";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < random_sentence.size(); ++i) {
    cout << ' ' << random_sentence[i];
}
system("Pause");
return 0;
}

void find_Poop_inSentence(vector<string> & v1, vector<string> & v2, string sub) {
int iterOne;
int iterTwo = 0;
int iteratorMax = v2.size();


for (iterOne = 0; iterOne < iteratorMax; iterTwo++) {

    if (v1[iterOne] == v2[iterTwo]) {
        v2[iterTwo] == sub;
    }
    if (iterTwo == iteratorMax ) {
        iterOne++;
        iterTwo = 0;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to my friend Ivan Drago I was able to solve this.

```
void find_Poop_inSentence(vector<string> & v1, vector<string> & v2, string sub);

int main()
{
cout << "Howdy partner, tell me some words you don't take kindly to.\n";
vector<string>bad_words;
string word;

while (cin >> word)
{
    //cin.ignore();
    bad_words.push_back(word);
    if (word == "exit")
        break;

}
cout << "Ok partner, got it!\n";
cout << "Now say something and I'll repeat it back to you. Don't worry, I'll bleep out the words that you don't like.\n";
cout << "Push enter twice when done.\n";

word = "";
vector<string> random_sentence;
while (cin >> word)
{
    //cin.ignore();
    random_sentence.push_back(word);
    if (cin.get() == '\n')
        break;

}

find_Poop_inSentence(bad_words, random_sentence, "****");

cout << "You said: ";
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < random_sentence.size(); ++i) {
    cout << ' ' << random_sentence[i];
}
system("Pause");
return 0;
}

void find_Poop_inSentence(vector<string> & v1, vector<string> & v2, string sub) {

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++) {

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < v2.size(); j++) {
        if (v1[i] == v2[j]) {
            v2[j] = sub;
        }

    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more work to do than just the part with the question marks. Even if you managed to implement the replacement part, your code will still won't work.

```
find(bad_words.begin(), bad_words.end(), say_back) != bad_words.end())
```

`find()` searches the sequence given by the first two parameters, the beginning and the ending iterator values. These are your `bad_words`. `find()` checks for the first occurence of the value given by the third parameter, and return the iterator referencing the first found value, or `end()` if the value was not found.

So, if bad_words contained "Fudge", and you typed "Fudge" into `say_back`, `find()` will find it.

However, if you typed in "Definitely Fudge" into `say_back`, `find()` won't find it, of course. Because none of your `bad_words` contain "Definitely Fudge", exactly. `find()` searches for an exact match.

So, if you were hoping to "replace any bad words found in the" `say_back` string, this will not work.

Before you can even begin to think about replacing any `bad_words` in `say_back`, you need to figure out the right algorithm. You need to find each individual word in `say_back`, and then check each individual word in `bad_words`.

Until you can correctly implement the search algorithm, figuring out how to replace something that you found in `bad_words` is, in a manner of speaking, putting the cart before the horse.

You need to figure this out first; if needed you can always [talk to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: fml. will edit and repost. sorry. had been working on this without much sleep and my brains hurt. ty for response

Comment: Did you talk to your rubber duck, yet, as I suggested?

Comment: Yeah and the duck is starting to talk back and make fun of me

Comment: Did your duck ask you why, in your new loop, each time you get() a single character, you push_back() an entire string into random_sentence, which is always empty and never changes?

Comment: when i remove that it sets word to "exit" and repeats over and over... my have pity on my brain

Comment: "Debug Assertion failed. Vector subscript out of range"